Compute the Expected Codeword Length when using a Huffman-Code for a Source that Generates the German Alphabet
Lemma we have to use:
Let $ E(p_1, \dots, p_n) $ be the average codeword length of a Huffman code for an alphabet with $ n $ letters and probabilities $ p_1, \dots, p_n $. Let $ p_1 $ and $ p_2 $ be the smallest probabilities. Then we know that the following holds:
$$
E(p_1, \dots, p_n) = E(p_1 + p_2, p_3, \dots, p_n) + p_1 + p_2.
$$
Exercise:
The frequencies of letters in the German language are:
space ($17.5 \%$), E ($14.3 \%$), N ($8.6 \%$), R ($6.7 \%$), I ($6.2 \%$), S ($5.3 \%$), T ($4.6 \%$), D ($4.3 \%$), H, A (each $4.2 \%$), U ($3.1 \%$), L ($2.8 \%$), C, G (each $2.6 \%$), M ($2.1 \%$), O ($1.7 \%$), B ($1.6 \%$), Z, W (each $1.4 \%$), F ($1.3 \%$), K ($0.9 \%$), V ($0.7 \%$), Ü ($0.6 \%$), P, Ä (each $0.5 \%$), Ö ($0.2 \%$), J ($0.1 \%$), Q, X, Y (each $0.02 \%$).
What is the expected codeword length of the corresponding Huffman code?
Note: Do not construct the code tree, but use the above Lemma.
My Question:
is there any elegant trick to it? Because if I just always have to recursively repeat the steps (and thus especially always have to check what the smallest new probabilities are, after merging symbols together, i.e. constructed the modified alphabet for this step), I do not see what makes this lemma better than just using the code-tree.
Can anyone help?

I doubt there is an elegant trick, but the recursion (including check) is not difficult to code, and that seems to be what you are being asked to produce.  If the code tree is as easy then you could use it to check your result.

Just to be safe there is no misunderstanding: you suggest that it most probably is about programming it in whatever language, say R or Python, correct? Then, of course, the Lemma makes a small programm possible in order to yield the solution.

Just try to merging the two smallest probabilities and apply the Lemma iteratively.
Step 1. Merge 0.0002 + 0.0002 = 0.0004, then the new list is
0.0004, 0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.009, 0.013, 0.014, 0.014, 0.016, 0.017, 0.021, 0.026, 0.026, 0.028, 0.031, 0.042, 0.042, 0.043, 0.046, 0.053, 0.062, 0.067, 0.086, 0.143, 0.175
Step 2. Merge  0.0004 + 0.001 = 0.0014, then the new list is
0.0014, 0.002, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.009, 0.013, 0.014, 0.014, 0.016, 0.017, 0.021, 0.026, 0.026, 0.028, 0.031, 0.042, 0.042, 0.043, 0.046, 0.053, 0.062, 0.067, 0.086, 0.143, 0.175
.... and so on. we keep merging the two smallest values and adding their sum to the expected length.
